Upload pictures and Videos from attachements in database, not URL to Facebook Graph using ASP.NET C# SDK
I haven't found any examples for using FacebookClient to upload photos to a Facebook page in C#. I tried using the JavaScript SDK, but it exposes a lot of functionality I don't need. I'm implementing the upload functionality with FacebookClient in my custom Facebook service.
I'm encountering issues, and the photo needs to be under 4 MB and in JPG, PNG, GIF, TIFF, or HEIF format. Can anyone provide guidance or examples for this specific scenario?
